# PDO Multi-query "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm still learning PDO so I might of missed something but basically I'm trying to insert a row into a table and then select the generated id.

I'm not sure if it likes both queries in one pdo statement. Here is the code I'm using to execute the SQL.

```
public function ExecuteQuery($sql, $params = array())
    {

        if($this->_handle == null)
            $this->Connect();

        $query = $this->_handle->prepare($sql);

        foreach($params as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_int($value)){
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }else if(is_bool($value)){
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            }else if(is_null($value)){
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_NULL);
            }else{
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        $query->execute();

        $x = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        var_dump($x);

        return $x;
    }
```

This function is part of a database class, $this->_handle is the PDO object.

```
public function Connect()
    {
        try {
          $this->_handle = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$this->_host.';dbname='.$this->_database, $this->_username, $this->_password);
          $this->_handle->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

And the SQL I'm running is this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`Username`, `Password`, `PasswordSalt`, `Email`, `IsAdmin`, `LoginAttempts`, `LastLogin`, `LastLoginAttempt`, `Created`) VALUES (:username, :password, :passwordsalt, :email, :isadmin, :loginattempts, :lastlogin, :lastloginattempt, :created); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'id'
```

The user is created and is there in the users table but it errors after that.

Can anyone see what am doing wrong?  :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the mysql driver for PDO (maybe mysql itself?) does not support multi-query prepared statements.

Instead of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your query, use `Conexion::$cn->lastInsertId()` after your `$query->execute()`

Comment: I do think it was because the pdo driver was using mysql_query underneath which doesnt support multiple queries, i've since gone back to using mysqli's multi_query and its working fine :)

Comment: with pdo_mysql, to use multiple queries you have to setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true) on you PDO or PDOStatement. also pdo does not use mysql_query underneath... it's a way of replacing mysql_* extension

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct:

```
function ExecuteQuery($sql, $params = array())
{
    if(Conexion::$cn== null)
        Conexion::Connect();
    $paramString="";

    foreach($params as $k=>$v)
    {
        $param = " :".$k." ,";
        $paramString .= $param;
    }
    $sql.=substr($paramString,0,-2);
    $query = Conexion::$cn->prepare($sql);
    foreach($params as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "entro";
        $query->bindParam(":".$key, $value);
    }

    $query->execute();
    $x = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($x);
    return $x;
}

public function Connect()
{
    try {
        $dns='dblib:host='.Conexion::$server.";dbname=".Conexion::$db.";";
        Conexion::$cn = new \PDO($dns, Conexion::$user, Conexion::$passw);
        Conexion::$cn->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```