# Put an image into a SQLite database

Tags: php, database, image, sqlite, pdo

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401761/remote-image-file-to-sqlite-blob-in-php) I should use `fopen`. I have done this but in my example I'm using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`.

```
$query->bindValue(':'.$key, fopen($value, "rb"), PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

`$value` contains the path to the file (/var/www/html/....jpg).

I tried this but when I open SQLiteManager with the specific entry I get `[Exception ... "Component returened failure code 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED)`.

Why doesn't this work?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8094623/426227) is how the rest of my implementation looks like.

***Edit:***

`file_get_contents` brings me the same error.

**Perhaps it is a problem with the php modules?**

`SELECT sqlite_version()` brings me 3.7.7.1

`phpinfo()` gives me

Configure Command: '--without-sqlite'

additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite.ini

SQLite:

> PECL Module version    2.0-dev $Id: sqlite.c,v 1.166.2.13.2.9 2007/05/19 17:58:22 iliaa Exp $
>
> SQLite Library     2.8.17
>
> SQLite Encoding    UTF-8
>
> PDO drivers    mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2

pdo_sqlite

> PECL Module version    1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6.2.2 2007/03/23 14:30:00 wez Exp $
>
> SQLite Library     3.3.6

PDO:

> PDO drivers    mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2

***Edit 2:***

This is how I can display the BLOB images. `getimage.php`

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg");

require_once('class.DatabaseQuery.php');

$db = new DatabaseQuery();
$name = sqlite_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$sql = "SELECT image FROM $name WHERE _id=:id;";

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->ExecuteQuery($sql, array("id"=>$id));

echo $result[0]['image'];
```

Display images: `<img src='getimage.php?name=$printname&id=" . $row['_id'] . "' heigth='75' width='75' alt='Test' />`

So I can display the images. But how can I insert an image in the database?

Comment: You don't know why I'm needing this. I want to fill a SQLite database with content (in this case also images). The database is for a mobile client which only downloads one file (the database). This is my handicap and I have to do this.

Comment: If you just want to download a single file, why not make it a zip archive containing the db and an image directory?

Comment: Different clients can have different versions, so I would need to create different versions of image directories too. Additionally, the implementation of different clients has to be changed too. So currently I want to keep the solution of storing images in the database. It is possible because SQLiteManager can store an image as BLOB. Why this shouldn't be possible by a PHP script?

Comment: You may be getting this error if the database was created with sqlite2 and you're opening with sqlite3.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Regarding the linked post. I'm not sure about its ridiculousness. I explained what the OP was doing wrong and gave a bit of code to correctly insert a blob. You can make an argument against keeping images in the db but how does that make my post ridicule?

Comment: @testing Are you using both the pdo_sqlite (SQLite 3) and sqlite (2) extensions on the same database file. You may want to use `new PDO("sqlite2:filename") when using PDO if you do so.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin: How do I find out with wich version the database was created? `SELECT sqlite_version()` brings me 3.7.7.1. I only use this call for openening the connection: `$this->_handle = new PDO("sqlite:"."database.db");`. This works for adding entries except of BLOB images. If I try your code I get `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` on `prepare`, `setAttribute` ...

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin well it seems I was wrong. I had no idea that PDO can bind a file pointer. my apologies.

Comment: Warning, you are vurnerable to SQL injection. `getimage.php?name=1; DROP TABLE xxx;--`

Comment: @Benoit: Thanks for your warning! But currently I only solved it partially. How can I prepare a statement in the `FROM` part of the `SELECT`? I tried this and get the error `General error: 1 near ":name": syntax error`

Comment: @testing i don't think you can bind anywhere else than in the WHERE clause. just use an SQL escaper. also, seems like [ruby supports sqlite3/blobs](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/faq.html#538670656). i don't think the php api supports it.

Comment: @user309483: How does such a SQL escaper looks like? A simple `str_replace` of single and double quotes?

Comment: @testing: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will avoid a lot of headaches if you encode your file and save it in a text field.

`$dataToSave = base64_encode(file_get_contents('filename'));`

To read you will need a base64_decode.

Comment: I also tried to get the image into the database by using `base64_encode` and `bin2hex`. The images in the database are somehow hex decoded and saved as `BLOB`. I would have to ask the developers of the clients how they deal with the images now and if they could switch to `base64_encode`. In the meantime I managed to display the images from the database. So I can display BLOB images, I can even input BLOB images with SQLiteManager. It shouldn't be that hard to insert an image with PHP. But if I don't get this managed your answer would be the only solution I think.